Graph API - Filter the drive items based on name
I am trying to get the drive items using Graph api.
The filter currently i am trying to use is to get the name value. For example: the DriveItem name is "Business Impact Statement", i am sending request to get the name that contains "Impact". But the "contains" is not working.
Below Graph API call works:
GET request "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{mydriveID}/children?%24filter=startsWith(name,'Business')&top=50"
This is not working:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{mydriveID}/children?%24filter=contains(name,'Impact')&top=50
contains not working for the name filter
My expectation is even if i search with the contained value in the name, the graph api should return the result. Is there something am i missing here? Could someone please advise how to handle this scenario using Graph API?

AFAIK The contains function is not directly supported for name filtering in Microsoft Graph API queries. However, you can use the $search query parameter to achieve similar results. The $search parameter

Check this https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{mydriveID}/children?$search="name:Impact"&$top=50

I have tried using search like you have suggested., https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/children?$select=name&$search="name:Impact"&$top=50... It returns all the files contained under the drive with this search query, but not the expected result. @Rukmini

AFAIK contains is not supported for name filtering

Yes, looks its not supported. Do we have any other way to get the search results? @Rukmini

Will check and update

@Rukmini Thanks, Will be waiting for your response


Note that: The contains function is not supported for name filtering in Microsoft Graph API queries.


You can use the $search or startsWith query parameter to achieve similar results as a workaround:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/DriveID/children?$search="name:XXX"&$top=50




But using the $search query parameter, it returns all the files under the drive.

As mentioned by you make use of startsWith query parameter as there is no workaround for contains:

Reference:
[Graph API SharePoint List Search (Contains & StartsWith) Not Working - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1016924/graph-api-sharepoint-list-search-(contains-startsw) by Srinivasa Rao Darna
